# scrollbar in Top level canvas

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

scrollbar in Top level window created for a canvas is not working and how do I get region of canvas. where canvas size varies with number of buttons in it

I have created frame in tk(root) and one widget in a frame creates Top level window , which has multiple Buttons in a Frame.Number of Button varies with list. That Frame(which has buttons in it) exists in a canvas. My problem is that after putting scroll widget canvas do not moves

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.geometry("500x200")
my_app= Frame(root)
my_app.pack()
my_window = Toplevel(my_app, bg='brown')
my_window.geometry("500x200+300+500")

top_window = Frame(my_window, bd=2, relief=SUNKEN)
top_window.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

yscrollbar = Scrollbar(top_window)
yscrollbar.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=N+S)

canvas = Canvas(top_window, bd=0, yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set)
canvas.config(scrollregion=(0, 0, 500, 1000))
canvas.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=N+S+E+W)

yscrollbar.config( command = canvas.yview)
top_window.pack()
my_f = Frame(canvas)
def ins_ind(m):
    print(m)

results = 
["one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","ten"]
ins_list=[]

for ind, result in enumerate(results):
    ins=str(result)
    ins_list.append(ind)
    ins_list[ind] = Button(my_f, text = ins, font='Times 12 bold', 
        bg='sandy brown',anchor=E, fg="black", command = lambda m=ins: 
    ins_ind(m) )
    ins_list[ind].pack()
my_f.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Scroll bar do no moves

Comment: What exactly is supposed to be scrolled by the `Scrollbar`—just the canvas?

Answer (score 0):

For the buttons to move when you scroll the canvas you must put the buttons on the canvas.

Your code puts the buttons on the frame `my_f`. To put the buttons on the canvas you should use: `canvas.create_window(x, y, window=button)`.